# Find combinations of a column of comma separated categories

Tags: r, combinations

I have a column of multiple categories in a comma separated pattern. something Like that

| id | categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, C, D |
| 2 | A, F, X, G |
| 3 | B, Y, X, D |

How can I produce two columns with the possible occurrences of two categories, something like that

| id | category 1 | category 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 1 | A | C |
| 1 | A | D |
| 1 | B | C |
| 1 | B | D |
| 1 | C | D |
| 2 | A | F |
| 2 | A | X |
| 2 | A | G |

And so on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can split and use `combn`, i.e.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df$categories, ', '), function(i)data.frame(t(combn(i, 2)))))

#   X1 X2
#1   A  B
#2   A  C
#3   A  D
#4   B  C
#5   B  D
#6   C  D
#7   A  F
#8   A  X
#9   A  G
#10  F  X
#11  F  G
#12  X  G
#13  B  Y
#14  B  X
#15  B  D
#16  Y  X
#17  Y  D
#18  X  D
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    split(df,df$id),
    function(x){
      cbind(
        x$id,
        t(combn(strsplit(x$categories,", ")[[1]],2))
      )
    }
  )
)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "1"  "A"  "B" 
 [2,] "1"  "A"  "C" 
 [3,] "1"  "A"  "D" 
 [4,] "1"  "B"  "C" 
 [5,] "1"  "B"  "D" 
 [6,] "1"  "C"  "D" 
 [7,] "2"  "A"  "F" 
 [8,] "2"  "A"  "X" 
 [9,] "2"  "A"  "G" 
[10,] "2"  "F"  "X" 
[11,] "2"  "F"  "G" 
[12,] "2"  "X"  "G" 
[13,] "3"  "B"  "Y" 
[14,] "3"  "B"  "X" 
[15,] "3"  "B"  "D" 
[16,] "3"  "Y"  "X" 
[17,] "3"  "Y"  "D" 
[18,] "3"  "X"  "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, data.table(t(combn(scan(text = categories, what = "character", sep = ","), 2))), id]
Read 4 items
Read 4 items
Read 4 items
    id V1 V2
 1:  1  A  B
 2:  1  A  C
 3:  1  A  D
 4:  1  B  C
 5:  1  B  D
 6:  1  C  D
 7:  2  A  F
 8:  2  A  X
 9:  2  A  G
10:  2  F  X
11:  2  F  G
12:  2  X  G
13:  3  B  Y
14:  3  B  X
15:  3  B  D
16:  3  Y  X
17:  3  Y  D
18:  3  X  D
```

Or, we can use `dplyr` pipeline like below

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(categories = list(data.frame(t(combn(unlist(strsplit(categories, ", ")), 2))))) %>%
  unnest(categories) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives

```
      id X1    X2
   <int> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 A     B
 2     1 A     C
 3     1 A     D
 4     1 B     C
 5     1 B     D
 6     1 C     D
 7     2 A     F
 8     2 A     X
 9     2 A     G
10     2 F     X
11     2 F     G
12     2 X     G
13     3 B     Y
14     3 B     X
15     3 B     D
16     3 Y     X
17     3 Y     D
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:3, categories = c("A, B, C, D", "A, F, X, G",
"B, Y, X, D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using tidyverse:

1. Use `strsplit()` (or `stringr::str_split()` to obtain each of the categories from the original data.
2. Split the data by `id` and then generate a sub-dataframe for that id with each of the possible combinations.
3. Join the tables back together (this step can conveniently with the same function as step 2 using `purrr::map_df()`).

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(all = str_split(categories, ", ")) %>% 
  split(.$id) %>% 
  map_df(function(df) {
    combs = t(combn(unlist(df$all), m = 2))
    tibble(id = df$id, cat_1 = combs[, 1], cat_2 = combs[, 2])
  })
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 3
      id cat_1 cat_2
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 A     B    
 2     1 A     C    
 3     1 A     D    
 4     1 B     C    
 5     1 B     D    
 6     1 C     D    
 7     2 A     F    
 8     2 A     X    
 9     2 A     G    
10     2 F     X    
11     2 F     G    
12     2 X     G    
13     3 B     Y    
14     3 B     X    
15     3 B     D    
16     3 Y     X    
17     3 Y     D    
18     3 X     D
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gregexpr`.

```
z <- dat$categories
t(do.call(cbind, lapply(regmatches(z, gregexpr(z, pa='\\w')), combn, 2)))
#      [,1] [,2]
#  [1,] "A"  "B" 
#  [2,] "A"  "C" 
#  [3,] "A"  "D" 
#  [4,] "B"  "C" 
#  [5,] "B"  "D" 
#  [6,] "C"  "D" 
#  [7,] "A"  "F" 
#  [8,] "A"  "X" 
#  [9,] "A"  "G" 
# [10,] "F"  "X" 
# [11,] "F"  "G" 
# [12,] "X"  "G" 
# [13,] "B"  "Y" 
# [14,] "B"  "X" 
# [15,] "B"  "D" 
# [16,] "Y"  "X" 
# [17,] "Y"  "D" 
# [18,] "X"  "D"
```

By ID's

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, by(dat, dat$categories, \(x) {
  z <- x$categories
  cbind(id=x$id, 
        t(do.call(cbind, lapply(regmatches(z, gregexpr(z, pa='\\w')), combn, 2))))
}))
#                id X1 X2
# A, B, C, D.1    1  A  B
# A, B, C, D.2    1  A  C
# A, B, C, D.3    1  A  D
# A, B, C, D.4    1  B  C
# A, B, C, D.5    1  B  D
# A, B, C, D.6    1  C  D
# A, F, X, G.1    2  A  F
# A, F, X, G.2    2  A  X
# A, F, X, G.3    2  A  G
# A, F, X, G.4    2  F  X
# A, F, X, G.5    2  F  G
# A, F, X, G.6    2  X  G
# B, Y, X, D.1    3  B  Y
# B, Y, X, D.2    3  B  X
# B, Y, X, D.3    3  B  D
# B, Y, X, D.4    3  Y  X
# B, Y, X, D.5    3  Y  D
# B, Y, X, D.6    3  X  D
```

**Note:** `"R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"`

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:3, categories = c("A, B, C, D", "A, F, X, G", 
"B, Y, X, D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```